# Add objects from GroupBy into a list

Tags: c#, linq

I was working on a Linq query with some GroupBy. I have a List of `A` object with five properties, and I want to create a new List of `Result` object.
The goal is to have a list of one properties where other properties are same (the first column is always the same value for each line).

example :

```
A | B1 | C1 | 1 | 1      A | B1 | C1,C2 | 1 | 1
A | B1 | C2 | 1 | 1  =>  A | B2 | C1    | 1 | 1
A | B2 | C1 | 1 | 1
```

I achieve to create the Linq query to groupBy the properties, and then add it to a new list with a foreach loop.
Then I tried to add the objects directly in the Linq query, but the object are not added to the list.

Working code :

```
var group = table
            .GroupBy(x => x.p2)
            .Select(p2Grp => new
            {
                P2 = p2Grp.Key,
                Group = p2Grp.GroupBy(x => x.p4)
                    .Select(p4Grp => new
                    {
                        P4 = p4Grp.Key,
                        Group = p4Grp.GroupBy(x => x.p5)
                            .Select(p5Grp => new
                            {
                                P5 = p5Grp.Key,
                                P1 = p5Grp.First().p1,
                                P3 = p5Grp.Select(x => x.p3).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

var result = new List<Result>();

foreach (var p2Grp in group)
{
    foreach (var p4Grp in p2Grp.Group)
    {
        foreach (var p5Grp in p4Grp.Group)
        {
            result.Add(new Result
            {
                p1 = p5Grp.P1,
                p3 = p5Grp.P3,
                p2 = p2Grp.P2,
                p4 = p4Grp.P4,
                p5 = p5Grp.P5
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Do "anything" :

```
var result2 = new List<Result>();

table.GroupBy(x => x.p2)
    .Select(p2Grp => new
    {
        P2 = p2Grp.Key,
        Group = p2Grp.GroupBy(x => x.p4)
            .Select(p4Grp => new
            {
                P4 = p4Grp.Key,
                Group = p4Grp.GroupBy(x => x.p5)
                    .Select(p5Grp =>
                    {
                        result2.Add(new Result
                        {
                            p1 = p5Grp.First().p1,
                            p3 = p5Grp.Select(x => x.p3),
                            p2 = p2Grp.Key,
                            p4 = p4Grp.Key,
                            p5 = p5Grp.Key
                        });

                        return "";
                    })
            })
    });
```

My testing list and class :

```
var table = new List<A>
{
    new A { p1 = "A", p2 = "B1", p3 = "C1", p4 = 1, p5 = 1 },
    new A { p1 = "A", p2 = "B2", p3 = "C1", p4 = 1, p5 = 1 },
    new A { p1 = "A", p2 = "B1", p3 = "C2", p4 = 1, p5 = 1 },
    new A { p1 = "A", p2 = "B1", p3 = "C2", p4 = 1, p5 = 2 },
    new A { p1 = "A", p2 = "B1", p3 = "C2", p4 = 2, p5 = 1 },
};
```

```
public class A
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public string p3 { get; set; }
    public int p4 { get; set; }
    public int p5 { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> p3 { get; set; }
    public int p4 { get; set; }
    public int p5 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           var groups = table.GroupBy(x => new { p1 = x.p1, p2 = x.p2, p4 = x.p4, p5 = x.p5 }).ToList();

            List<Result> results = groups.Select(x => new Result()
            {
                p1 = x.Key.p1,
                p2 = x.Key.p2,
                p3 = x.Select(y => y.p3).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y).ToList(),
                p4 = x.Key.p4,
                p5 = x.Key.p5
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Working perfectly, it seem that the Distinct() and OrderBy are useless ?

Comment: Only with the sample data.  Real data may need Distinct and OrderBy.